# How to install ubuntu software packages permanently

Tags: 14.04, updates

I am just executing these below commands frequently, But all the commands are working fine , and If I execute these commands after few more days, the same updates are getting downloaded , this consumes more bandwidth of Internet, so I am running out of Internet,, For Example ,Google chrome and firefox are frequently downloading when I update through below commands , How to solve this

```
sudo apt-get update        # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt-get upgrade       # Strictly upgrades the current packages
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # Installs updates (new ones)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All packages are installed permanently. The reason you are receiving repeated updates of Firefox and Chrome is because Mozilla and Google frequently push minor updates to those applications. If bandwidth consumption is an issue, then I would suggest just updating less frequently to avoid downloading every minor update and waiting for some more major changes.